# Problem with string format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to assign string "{"MY_URL", "MY"}" to string variable. So in my code behind (C#)
I wrote like `string str ="{\"MY_URL\", \"MY\"}"`. When i will assign this to textbox it will print escape character ("\") as well. That i don't want so what i have to do to achieve this??

Comment: With "assign this to textbox" do you mean you enter that string (with escape characters) in a textbox control? Or assign it to the `Text` property?

Comment: i could not understand. do u need comma or \ character between ur url  and MY ?? give us one example..

Comment: Put some effort to make your question relevant, as of now doesn't make sense

Comment: doing this code in SVC.cs file and output of that i have assign texbox , when i will test it with aspx.cs page then it is fine but in svc.cs file there is some issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When i will assign this to textbox it will print escape character ("\") as well.

It shouldn't, and it doesn't on my side, at least on a vanilla VS 2008 ASP.Net application.  Perhaps you have explained this question wrong?

Comment: doing this code in SVC.cs file and output of that i have assign texbox , when i will test it with aspx.cs page then it is fine but in svc.cs file there is some issue

Comment: Well, escape characters don't exist at runtime, they are instructions for the compiler to take the next character literally, and not as a special character.  If you are using Visual Studio to debug, it will show you the value of the string with the escape characters in it, but that doesn't mean it will be output to a label like that.  Try it for yourself on a simple page; if you really are seeing those characters output, something else is doing it.

Comment: From this:  "output of that i have assign texbox" I am guessing that the characters exist in the string because you are inputting it like that, into a textbox, and then asking for it's value.  In that case, of course the escape characters will be there.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested this on my end, and it is working as expected.

```
string str = "{\"PCT51_URL\", \"MY\"}";
TextBox1.Text = str;// this is working fine to me.
```

But if it is still not working for you, you can replace those. e.g.

```
TextBox1.Text = str.Replace("\\","");
```

**Note:** I am using `VS2010`

Comment: doing this code in SVC.cs file and output of that i have assign texbox , when i will test it with aspx.cs page then it is fine but in svc.cs file there is some issue and TextBox1.Text = str.Replace("\\",""); not worked;